# an unknown acount is created on my CPanel server

Tags: linux, centos, user-accounts

I just installed CPanel on my server and after a few hours I received notification of a new account called "karukradi"

does anyone know whats this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you got owned if you didn't create that account. Control panel apps like CPanel and phpMyAdmin are quick ways to get owned. Consider learning how to administer your server without these crutches and you'll be better off in the long run.

Comment: It was just a few hours I setup my server and I didn't even had any website on my server how could that happen ?

Comment: Automated bots.